# Standard naming conventions for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, naming-conventions

Being in the beginning of a project in Objective-C, I'm gathering different kind of information and I would like to find a good naming convention.

Does such resource exist ?

- Official
- Unofficial but still widely used

Comment: Naming convention: it's called Objective-C, with caps.

Comment: @H2CO3 Should start by spelling the language's name properly, thank you ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the [Cocoa official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH).

Comment: Google also has a great [Objective C Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml) with extensive explanations and suggestions

Comment: Have you seen any of Google's objective-c code? It's a mess. It looks like it was written by java devs that hate objc. Their style guide is totally out of date too.

Answer (score 6):

additionally to the standart coding conventions published by Apple, I want to hint to [Matt Gemmell's great article about API Design](http://mattgemmell.com/2012/05/24/api-design/), that also covers naming conventions for protocols used in delegation.